# Comma Before and After "In Part"?

Tags: grammar

In saying thanks in part to, would adding a comma before and after the phrase "in part" be considered correct?

The decline in crime was thanks, in part, to the efforts of the city's growing police department.

or

The decline in crime was thanks in part to the efforts of the city's growing police department.

Comment: What do you think? Please explain why you think that, and then explain what the source of your confusion is.

Comment: Both with and without are fine. It's a matter of intent and style.

Answer (score 1):

Commas.  I feel a slight pause needed.  There is an old saw that advises for a comma, "If in doubt, leave it out."  Commas are more an art than a science.  Contrast this sentence:  I slipped mainly because there were no caution signs, but in part because I was running.  "In part" is not an afterthought and should not be set apart.

Answer (score -2):

I think commas work better for more elegant speakers within the story. Such as if the speaker has a British accent, or something like that.